# Recreating an Excel graph

Tags: excel, graph

I've been working through some Excel tasks today - most successfully. I'm almost finished my current task, but can't figure out how to replicate a graph.

The two graphs in the bottom right are the ones I'm trying to recreate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rprGQ.jpg

This is my work so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acf87.jpg
Could a sage offer any help?

Comment: what is the version of excel you are using now?

Comment: Do you have problem with data or you want to know about creation of Graph?

Comment: [This](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/QuickChartVBA.html)  might help for the beginning.

Comment: Excel 2011. I can't figure out how to create the graphs in the first image. I've tried selecting pretty much every possible combination off data, and clicked through all the templates, but can't recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart 1: First you need to populate the Quantity forecasts for 2015 and 2016. Then (temporarily if necessary) clear the darker blue highlighted cell shown in the screenshot below, and select the light and dark blue highlighted cells in the screenshot (select one area, then hold Ctrl while selecting the others, so all are selected/highlighted at once). Then insert a line chart. Don't try to duplicate the ugly dots and dashed lines, just use different colors which will reproduce differently if photocopied.

[image]

It can be difficult to select that many ranges at once, particularly using a laptop's touchpad. Here's an alternative.

Select just the 2014 values (not including the cell that says "2014" at the top), and insert a line chart.

Right click the chart, and click Select Data from the popup menu. In the dialog, click the Edit button just below Horizontal Axis Labels on the right. Click in the Axis Label Range box and select the list of permit types, and click OK. This populates the right hand list with labels instead of the numbers 1, 2, 3, etc.

Then select Series1 in the left hand list, and click Edit immediately above it. The Series Values box is fine; click in the Series Name box, then select the cell that contains "2014". Click OK.

Click Add. Click in the Series Name box, and select the cell that says "2015", click OK. Click in the Series Values box, delter "={1}, and select the cells containing the 2015 data.

Repeat this last step for the 2016 data.

[image]

Chart 2: Same protocol as Chart 1.